# How to get the performance statistics using instrumentation in Android

Tags: android, performance-testing, android-instrumentation

For an android application can i get performance statistics like memory used, cpu load, battery consumption ..etc using instumentation process/classes in android. if not in what way other than traceview/device moniter can i get these details(probably a file will be generated). can any body suggest the correct way.thanks